# Latex, Getting syntax error

Tags: pdftex

I have a big document (thesis). All was working well but I as as I upgraded version from ***basic-miktex-2.9.6022*** to ***basic-miktex-2.9.6361-x64***,
I am getting errors. How can I know what causes these errors and how to avoid it.

[image]

Error list....

```
Syntax Error (42287): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (47108): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (75545): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (115798): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (26395): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (36247): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (39552): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (14992): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (77660): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (1103): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (19769): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (35450): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (112695): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (330776): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (219010): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (1188022): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'
```

Comment: When are you getting these errors? Not with TeX and friends, I guess, but with a PDF viewer.

Comment: I already made a bug report. Should be sorted out soon: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2605/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question essentially is a MiKTeX bug report

Comment: Sad to see that there are at least 3 instances of this issue and all are forced closed wita proper solution. Apparently MiKTeX needs to be updated. Just search for `MikTex Update (Admin)` and update all the updatable packages. The trick is to run the `Admin` version of `MikTex Update`. That's it!