# Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Tags: luatex, miktex

I just installed TeXstudio on my new laptop with Windows 10 as OS. I tried to compile my old Latex documents which were written under a Windows 7 OS and obtain the following error:

```
Process started: lualatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Main".tex

Syntax Error (1446): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1459): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (675): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (675): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Process exited with error(s)
```

I have to mention that this error never occured on my old laptop where I runned TeXstudio successfully.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373173/124577). It's a problem of pdf images.

Comment: Imho it has been fixed (also for lualatex), the example in my bug report works fine for me. If your system is up-to-date and you still get it, you will have to make a minimal example.

Comment: But how do I fix this on my computer? Do I have to reinstall TeXstudio or Miktex again?

Comment: This is a MikTeX bug https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2605/. Try to update or reinstall MikTeX.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question essentially is a MiKTeX bug report

Comment: Sad to see that there are at least 3 instances of this issue and all are forced closed wita proper solution. Apparently MiKTeX needs to be updated. Just search for `MikTex Update (Admin)` and update all the updatable packages. The trick is to run the `Admin` version of `MikTex Update`. That's it!

Comment: Sad to see that there are at least 3 instances of this issue and all are forced closed wita proper solution. Apparently MiKTeX needs to be updated. Just search for `MikTex Update (Admin)` and update all the updatable packages. The trick is to run the `Admin` version of `MikTex Update`. That's it!